# Can we calculate range of a data if we only know mean, SD and N?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

Can we calculate range of a data if we only know mean=42.2, SD=9.61 and N=43?
Thank you,
Mitra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, in order to **estimate** the range of your data, you need to know the **distribution** of the data, the **mean** and the **standard deviation**.

There are some particular/special cases whereby knowing only the mean, SD and N you can find the range but I do not think that this applies to your case unless I miss something. Think that you have the following equations:

1. (X1+X2+...+X43)/43 = 42.2
2. ((X1-mean)^2+...+(X43-mean)^2)/(43-1) = 9.61^2

and you need to find the min and max Xi.

Comment: Yes you are right. These are my equations. and I am out of clue if it is possible to calculate range. Seems the answer is NO right?

Comment: Unless it asks you to calculate a confidence interval for the mean